# YouTube api publishedAfter publishedBefore not working

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to only show YouTube videos from a specific year. Why is it not working?

```
buildApiRequest('GET' URL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=your api key'
             &"home"=true
             &"publishedAfter"=2007-04-"01T00%3A00%3A00Z"
             &"publishedBefore"=2009-05-"01T00%3A00%3A00Z"
```

Comment: Hello. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide more information so we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself (see [mcve]). Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and will most likely not be answered. **For more Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: For me the API is also not working as expected, ignoring the `publishedAfter` filter. YouTube API is notorious for being constantly broken here or there.